# Transition rate derivation in non-relativistic quantum scattering

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, integration, dirac-delta-distributions, fermis-golden-rule

I am reading Principles of Quantum Mechanics by Shankar, here's a derivation I am puzzled.

To evaluate probability of particle entering detector in some solid angle, using $S$-matrix and Fermi's Golden Rules gives:

$$\begin{align}R_{i\rightarrow d\Omega}=&\frac{dP(p_i\rightarrow d\Omega)}{dt}\cr=&\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}[\int_{0}^{\infty}|\langle p_f|\hat{V}|p_i\rangle|^2\delta(\frac{p_f^2}{2\mu}-\frac{p_i^2}{2\mu})p_f^2dp_f] d\Omega.\end{align}\tag{19.3.1}$$

The evaluation of integral from Shankar gives $$=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|\langle p_f|\hat{V}|p_i\rangle|^2\mu p_i d\Omega.\tag{19.3.2}$$

I am not able to reduplicate this result, especially the integral involves $\delta$ function should gives  $p_i^2 ...$ so his result of $p_i$ looks bizarre to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very useful [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function) of the $\delta$ "function" is

$$\delta(f(x))=\sum_i\frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|},$$

where $x_i$ are the zeros of $f(x)$, i.e. $f(x_i)=0$, and $|f'(x_i)|$ means the absolute value of the derivative of $f$ evaluated at $x_i$. In your case, $f(x)$ would be $$f(p_f)=\frac{p_f^2}{2\mu}-\frac{p_i^2}{2\mu},$$

and zeros are $\pm p_i$. Then $$\delta\Big(\frac{p_f^2}{2\mu}-\frac{p_i^2}{2\mu}\Big)=\frac{\mu}{|p_i|}\Big(\delta(p_f-p_i)+\delta(p_f+p_i)\Big).$$

Note that the second term won't contribute to the integral, as it is from $0$ to $\infty$.