# Normalization of Hamiltonian Eigenfunctions for Free Particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions, normalization

I am trying to prove that given

$$\phi_E(x) = \left(\frac{m}{2E}\right)^{1/4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \hbar}} e^{i \sqrt{2mE}x/\hbar}$$

Then,

$$\int dx \phi^*_E \left(x\right) \phi_{E^\prime}(x) = \delta(E-E^\prime).$$

I tried and could not find an answer alone. I searched the internet and no luck. No book was helpful to me. These are supposed to be the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian of a free particle. The simplest possible quantum mechanics problem. This should be standard stuff. It is not for me. Can't find it! I am very frustrated. Please, if you have the knowledge of a simple proof, let me know and I will be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use one of the definitions of the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ik(x-x')}dk=\delta(x-x').$$

It would be

$$\int dx \phi^*_E(x)\phi_{E'}(x)=\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^{1/2}\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\frac{1}{(E E')^{1/4}}\int dxe^{i\frac{\sqrt{2m}}{\hbar}x\left(\sqrt{E'}-\sqrt{E}\right)}=\\ =\left(\frac{m}{2}\right)^{1/2}\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\frac{1}{(E E')^{1/4}}\frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2m}}\int dy e^{iy\left(\sqrt{E'}-\sqrt{E}\right)}=\frac{1}{2(E E')^{1/4}}\delta\left(\sqrt{E'}-\sqrt{E}\right).\tag{1}$$

Using [the property I mention in the comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/618596/279116), with $$f(E')=\sqrt{E'}-\sqrt{E},$$ whose zero is $E'=E$, and its derivative at that point is $$|f'(E)|=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{E}},$$

we have $$\delta\left(\sqrt{E'}-\sqrt{E}\right)=2\sqrt{E}\,\delta(E-E').$$

Inserting that in $(1)$, and substituting $E=E'$ due to the delta, we have

$$\int dx \phi^*_E(x)\phi_{E'}(x)=\delta(E-E')$$

Comment: I have already done that. I tried with that expression in all possible ways I know for a day and no luck. The problem, is that I don't get $\delta(E - E^\prime)$ I get $\delta(\sqrt(E)- \sqrt(E^\prime))$.

Comment: Use the property on this answer (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/618596/279116) to your case.

Comment: First, thank you for your time to help me! I tried that too. I started from the relation $p = \sqrt{2mE}$ relating momentum and energy of free particle. But as you can see to use that property in the other post you need to divide by the derivative of p in order to E at the place where p and E are zero. I may have done something wrong, but as far as I can tell it does not work.

Comment: I edited the answer to make things more explicit.

Comment: I wish I had a friend like you when I have problems like this! Thank you very much! Amazing explanation! Regards!